# Inner Join Using Lambda (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to write the following Linq (query style) in Lambda Expression so that I can chain and make my code more compact:

```
var result = from p1 in defaults
             join p2 in get on p1.PermissionName equals p2.PermissionName 
             into joined
             select new 
             {
                 PermissionName = p1.PermissionName, 
                 Permission = joined.Select(e => e.Permission == null ? false : true)
                                    .SingleOrDefault() 
             };
```

I could only go this far:

```
var result = defaults.Join(get, defaultKey => 
                          defaultKey.PermissionName, getKey => 
                          getKey.PermissionName, (a, b) => new 
                          { 
                              PermissionName = a.PermissionName, 
                              Permission = b.Permission 
                          });
```

As you can see that the `Join()` extension method does not provide a way to get the `joined` collection.
I also searched online but could not find any leads. Please feel free to suggest.

Comment: You're using `join ... into`, which is represented with `GroupJoin`, not `Join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin.aspx).

```
var result =
    defaults.GroupJoin(
        get,
        p1 => p1.PermissionName,
        p2 => p2.PermissionName,
        (p1, joined) =>
            new
            {
                PermissionName = p1.PermissionName,
                Permission = joined.Select(e => e.Permission != null)
                                   .SingleOrDefault()
            });
```